# Const double initialised from Lua

Tags: lua, constants

I have a global variable:

```
const double myvar = 5.1;
```

Now, I'm converting this to read these values from Lua.

However, I can't simply do:

```
const double myvar = lua_tonumber(L,1);
```

Since main() must first execute to start the Lua intepreter etc., but if I declare myvar afterwards, it will not be global.

Is there any way to do achieve a global const variable which takes it's value from Lua?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subtle ramifications of `const` can be fully understood only by language lawyers, but the basic idea of a const *variable* is that its value is specified at compile time.  Lua values cannot be created until there is a Lua interpreter, which requires calling `lua_open()`, which cannot be done until run time.  So **no**, there is no (safe, sane) way of having a `const` variable whose value is determined by Lua.

Answer (score 0):

You can *violate* constness like this:

```
*(double*) & myvar = lua_tonumber(L,1);
```

but it's a -very- bad practice.

**Edit**: Instead of declaring const variables you can do this:

```
static double myvar() {
 // todo: check if global L is init
 return lua_tonumber(L,1);
}
```

or even this:

```
static double myvar() {
 return 1.15;
}
```