# Is there any way to convert 'Double' or 'double' to 'const Double' or 'const double' in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, types

My question is similar to 
[Const double initialised from Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955418/const-double-initialised-from-lua)
but I am asking this question

```
Double W1 = -21.0;
const Double X = (const Double) W1;
```

is there any way to do so.

And is there any difference between:

```
    double Y;
    Double Y;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there any way to do so?

There isn't because a constant value has to be known at compile time, so you cannot assign it to a normal variable

> And is there any difference between: 
>   double Y; and Double Y;

Absolutely no difference, the first is an alias to the [actual type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If the symbol that you wish to behave as a constant is a field you could use the `readonly` modifier instead of constant. This will allow you to assign a value to the symbol either in the field initializer or the (static/non-static) constructor.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx):

> The readonly keyword differs from the
>   const keyword. A const field can only
>   be initialized at the declaration of
>   the field. A readonly field can be
>   initialized either at the declaration
>   or in a constructor. Therefore,
>   readonly fields can have different
>   values depending on the constructor
>   used. Also, although a const field is
>   a compile-time constant, the readonly
>   field can be used for run-time
>   constants, as in this line: public
>   static readonly uint l1 =
>   (uint)DateTime.Now.Ticks;

Example:

```
class A
{
    readonly double d;

    public A()
    {
        double w = -21.0;
        d = w;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually both the answers seems OK to me ... But here I got new idea.. Thanks.